# PHP preg_match_all with optional argument

Tags: php, regex

this regex problem exceeds my understanding of complex search patterns:
pattern:

```
<!--TAG\((\d+),([^0-9\)]\w*)\)-->
```

search text:

```
<!--TAG(204700,CS)-->
<!--TAG(204700,EN)-->
<!--TAG(204700,CS,def)-->
<!--TAG(204700,EN,rel)-->
```

The pattern finds me the first two links and puts the ID and language abbreviation into the return array. Now I need to adjust the pattern, so it would find also the third and fourth line a put the third optional argument into the return array. That is beyond me. Thanks for your help.

https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/qeu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add an optional part `(?:,(\w+))?` the matches a comma and captures in a group 1+ word characters:

`<!--TAG\((\d+),([^0-9\)]\w*)(?:,(\w+))?\)-->`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ktl3xL/1)

https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/qev

This part `[^0-9\)]\w*` is a negated character class which matches not a digit or a `)` which for example also matches `%`

Depending on your requirements, you might change that to `[A-Z]` or `\w+`